# How can I create a bootable USB stick for windows 8 on Ubuntu 14.10?

Tags: dual-boot, windows-8, 14.10

How can I create a bootable USB Stick for windows 8 on Ubuntu 14.10?

I have tried using startup disk creator but it doesn't show windows os.

Comment: It seems possible duplicate thread. The answer for your thread does seem in this link. http://askubuntu.com/questions/289559/how-can-i-create-a-windows-bootable-usb-stick-with-ubuntu

Answer (score -1):

You can create a bootable usb stick of windows 8 using Winusb. It offers a simple GUI for creating the bootable usb stick.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:colingille/freshlight
sudo sh -c "sed -i 's/utopic/saucy/g' /etc/apt/sources.list.d/colingille-freshlight-utopic.list"
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install winusb
```

Comment: winusb ppas are not updated for utopic unicorn. returns error: sed: can't read /etc/apt/sources.list.d/colingille-freshlight-utopic.list: No such file or directory